# Google customview example: Dot vs Cross Products

Tags: android

So I'm a newbie to android programming. This is a maths questions and I hope someone with a mathematics background would be able to help.

I have been looking at the customview example from google's website:
http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

At the very end of the code, there is a method called vectorToScalarScroll.

```
/**
 * Helper method for translating (x,y) scroll vectors into scalar rotation of the pie.
 *
 * @param dx The x component of the current scroll vector.
 * @param dy The y component of the current scroll vector.
 * @param x  The x position of the current touch, relative to the pie center.
 * @param y  The y position of the current touch, relative to the pie center.
 * @return The scalar representing the change in angular position for this scroll.
 */
private static float vectorToScalarScroll(float dx, float dy, float x, float y) {
    // get the length of the vector
    float l = (float) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    // decide if the scalar should be negative or positive by finding
    // the dot product of the vector perpendicular to (x,y). 
   float crossX = -y;
   float crossY = x;

   float dot = (crossX * dx + crossY * dy);
   float sign = Math.signum(dot);

   return l * sign;
}
```

I figured out that they are using the Pythagorean Formula for the float l variable here:

```
float l = (float) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
```

However, I'm not sure about the second part of the maths here, the one dealing with dot product.

From the way it is presented, it looks like they are calculating the cross product, not the dot product of the vector, the variables are even called crossX and crossY. They even mention the vector that is "perpendicular to (x,y)" which is why I'm thinking they mean a cross product instead.

From my research online, I came across this website:
http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/vectors-cross-product.html

The formula used seem to represent the one for Cz.

Does anyone know whether they are talking about a dot product or a cross product?

Comment: I think you'd do better asking at [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) . Simply just describe the process with mathematical variables instead of programming ones.

Comment: Is there a way I can move this question to the maths StackExchange or do I have to copy this thread, create a new thread there at maths StackExchangege, and paste?

Comment: I think there's a lot of information that won't be useful from mathematical point of view. So in my opinion (since it has no answers or votes here), I would delete the question here and post a new one there, which focuses solely on the math problem leaving some Android code aside.

Comment: Also note what is said in the link you posted. `The Dot Product gives a scalar (ordinary number) answer.Cross Product gives a vector as an answer.` So it might be Dot product after all.

Comment: Had to edit, misread the problem. But check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, had to edit I misread it:

It is just a bit long for a comment, but according to the definition of a dot product

> This operation can be defined either algebraically or geometrically. Algebraically, it is the sum of the products of the corresponding entries of the two sequences of numbers. Geometrically, it is the product of the magnitudes of the two vectors and the cosine of the angle between them.

So, as the comment says, the dot product of it's perp is

```
float dot = (crossX * dx + crossY * dy);
```

Which is the same as

```
float vector1 = crossX * dx;
float vector2 = crossY * dy;
float dot = vector1 + vector2
```

Recall:

> Algebraically, it is the sum of the products of the corresponding entries of the two sequences of numbers'

So this follows the definition of dot product.

Continuing:

The function `float sign = Math.signum(dot);` is just meant to determine the sign of the dot product (more can be seen here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), it may seem like overkill logically as you could do

```
if(dot < 0) return l * -1;
else return l;
```

But doing it the way you have posted, once we have determined our sign based on our dot product, you can apply that sign to the value

```
return l * sign;
```

or broken down into pieces

- dot product of perp vector:

  > float dot = (crossX * dx + crossY * dy);
- determine the sign of the dot product (+/-):

  > float sign = Math.signnum(dot);
- final value (our vector * perp dot product sign):

  > return l * sign;

There you have it, you have used the sum of your perp dot product to determine the sign of your vector.